# What's the purpose of verbose_name and help_text in Django model fieds?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm wondering what's the purpose of setting [`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) on Django model fields and how it's different from [`help_text`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#help-text). How are these being used by Django?

Comment: It is usually used in the Django admin pages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These names are used in the [*Django admin pages*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/). So instead of using the name of the model class, it will use the `verbose_name` of that model to make messages that are less "mechanical".

Furthermore you can use these in your own projects. For example if you want to obtain the `verbose_name` of a model you do not (statically) know, you can retrieve it with:

```
model._meta.verbose_name
```

This can be useful to write generic messages. You can write a warning message like:

```
Are you sure you want to delete the {{ obj._meta.verbose_name }}?
```

If your model is `PizzaTopping`, then the default `verbose_name` is `'pizza topping'`. It is more human friendly to write "*Are you sure you want to delete the pizza topping?*" than "*Are you sure you want to delete the PizzaTopping*?".

You can for example retrieve the `verbose_name` of a field with:

```
model._meta.get_field('some_field').verbose_name
```

Django's [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) furthermore use by default the (capitalized) `verbose_name` and the `help_text` as `label` and `help_text` in the form. If you thus render a model form, and you do *not* tweak the settings, it will take the `verbose_name`s of the model fields as labels, and the `help_text` will show up over that field.

Comment: I guess, you confuse the model's `verbose_name` with the field's :)

Comment: @planetp: no, the same applies for these of the fields. There are used in the admin pages as well.